# Jobs disabled by script are enabled when Jenkins restart

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-cli

I need to disable all scripts in a Jenkins Windows Instance. I use this script for that:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each
{
  println it.fullName + "-" + it.class
  it.disabled = true
};
```

All Jenkins are disabled correctly, as you can see in next image.

[image]

When i restart the instance, vía "service windows" or "restart safety" jobs are "enabled" again as you can see.
[image]

Any way to disable jobs permanently?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Script executed fine, but don't saved the state.
This script resolved the issue:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each
{
  println it.fullName + "-" + it.class
  it.disabled = true
  it.save()

};
```